# Maven build fails only for me - What could the issue be?

Tags: maven

I started working on a new project with a new team, a Java Maven project, the project is a big root multi-model maven project with 20+ Maven sub-projects.

I cloned it from gitlab, I got the `settings.xml` file from one of the new colleagues, I activated VPN, I made sure that I have access to the JFrog artifactory repository manager that I need for my dependencies, I ran `mvn clean install -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true` on the root project but the build fails, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project subproject-one: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:subproject-one:jar:20.3.0.0-DEV-SNAPSHOT: 
Could not find artifact com.example:subproject-two:jar:tests:20.3.0.0-DEV-SNAPSHOT in snapshots 
(http://omitted.artifactory.url:port/artifactory/libs-snapshot)
```

`subproject-two` is built before `subproject-one` hence the artifact for it exists in the local repository, apparently maven is looking for it in the remote repository first.

This works for everyone except for me. I think I checked everything that might be of an issue but everything seems to be the same as everyone who's already working and building the project successfully. Any ideas?

Comment: The given dep `com.example:subproject-two:jar:tests:20.3.0.0-DEV-SNAPSHOT` references a test-jar dependency which is presumably wrong... The question is where which part of the project will provide that dep?  Also you should not use `install` for such things better is to use `package` or verify to find reactor related issues (my guess is: a dependency is not correctly defined within the multi module build) but without the pom's it's hard to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had to run `mvn clean install` without skipping tests first, the reason why I avoided not skipping tests is because the build would fail because of some failed unit tests in the project, so what I did as a workaround is run this command: `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` so that the build wouldn bypass failed unit tests and keep on running, now I can build the project successfully with the command line option `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`.